# Regex testing negative pattern more than one word

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match string text which doesn't contain two words anywhere in the text. Those words are `ue` and `ui`. I've started of by working with one word before moving onto one or the other word, but I can't it to word with one word. Here is what I have tried so far :

```
^(?!ue)[A-Za-z\s]+(?<!ue)$
```

This works when `ue` is either at the begining or at the end of the test string. So in cases like this :

```
this is ue
ue is this
```

But not in this case, the above regex returns true which I don't want :

```
is ue really here
```

In addition I want to avoid matching `ue` as a part of another string i.e like the example below :

```
this is not supposed toue match
```

I don't want to match this with regex, but rather this instead :

```
this is not supposed to ue match
```

The difference is when `ue` is standalone word. How can I fix the regex above?

Comment: Any particular reason this has to be done as a single regex test?

Comment: yes I'm using evaluator from third party software which accepts regex. Otherwise I'd do it with something other than regex

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*\\bu[ei]\\b).*$   # use with singleline/dotall mode
```

An other way (more performant):

```
^(?>[^u]++|\\Bu|u(?![ei]\\b))*$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String regex = "(?:\\bue\\b|\\bui\\b)"
```

`\\b` is a [boundary matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) for word boundaries.  This will match any string that contains `ue` or `ui` that stand alone.

This can be simplified to:

```
String regex = "\\bu[ie]\\b"
```

@Casimir's approach is only necessary if you have to match using the entire region, as with `Matcher.matches()`; however, if you're using something like `Matcher.find()`, this is simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just change the + to a *, so it can handle there being no characters adjacent to it?

would it not be easier to just do a string.contains("ue")??